# axios post method just not responding with anything

Tags: reactjs, axios

i have this axios post method in my Action creator in my reactJS app but for some reason, I don't understand why, the post method is frozen and doesn't do anything. I have a similar implementation in my one of the other project that's working fine but this isn't. The console.log() shows nothing, no error no response. Please help, thanks in advance.

```
export const addNewPost = (data) =>(dispatch) => {

    dispatch(newPostLoading);
    console.log("addNewPost triggered");

    return (dispatch) => {
    
    axios
      .post("/posts.json", data)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
        dispatch(newPostSuc());
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        dispatch(newPostFailed(err));
      });
  };
};
```

This is what my caller component looks like :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { Button, Row, Col, Label } from 'reactstrap';
import { Control, LocalForm } from 'react-redux-form';
import { addNewPost } from '../redux/ActionCreators';
import {Loading} from './LoadingComponent';

class NewPost extends Component {
  
  addPostHandler = (event) => {
    const data ={
      title: event.title,
      author: event.author,
      content: event.content,
      image:''
    }
    this.props.addNewPost(data);
  };
  render() {

    if(this.props.newPost.isLoading)
    {
      return (<Loading/>);
    }


    let redirectElement = null;
    if (this.props.newPost.redirect) {
      redirectElement = <Redirect to="/" />;
    }
    return (
      <>
        {redirectElement}
        <div className="container">
          <LocalForm onSubmit={(values) => this.addPostHandler(values) }>
            <Row className="form-group">
                <Label htmlFor="title" md={2}><strong>Post Title</strong></Label>
                <Col md={10}>
                    <Control.text model=".title" id="title" name="title"
                        placeholder="Catchy title here bitch"
                        className="form-control"
                         />
                </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row className="form-group">
                <Label htmlFor="author" md={2}><strong>Author</strong></Label>
                <Col md={10}>
                    <Control.text model=".author" id="author" name="author"
                        placeholder="Author"
                        className="form-control"
                         />
                </Col>
            </Row>
          
            <Row className="form-group">
                <Label htmlFor="content" md={2}><strong>Post Description</strong></Label>
                <Col md={10}>
                    <Control.textarea model=".content" id="content" name="content"
                        rows="12" placeholder="You saw shit? Time to step on it"
                        className="form-control" />
                </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row className="form-group">
                <Col md={{size:10, offset: 2}}>
                    <Button type="submit" color="primary">
                    Send Post
                    </Button>
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </LocalForm>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    newPost: state.newPost
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
   addNewPost: (data) => {dispatch(addNewPost(data))}
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(NewPost);
```

Comment: I’m not sure what kind of help can be given with the information provided.

Comment: Are you calling the method that is returned ?

Comment: You should show what your request headers and response headers look like in the network tab.  This will usually show you what type of error you are getting when trying to call this.

Comment: @DaveNewton As requested, I have added my caller component? Please have a look at it. Thank you guys again.

Comment: @VictorJozwicki As requested, I have added my caller component. Please have a look at it. Thank you again.

Comment: @Michael As requested, I have added my caller component. Please have a look at it. Thank you  again.

Comment: Are you sure you’re calling a valid endpoint? `posts.json` doesn’t look like a valid endpoint

Comment: @ludwiguer My get requests are working fine with  the same endpoint. Can there be something wrong with post requests and not with get requests? I'm pretty new at this.

Comment: @ludwiguer Why not? E.g., that’s a Rails convention. The name of a URI is arbitrary.